# Halacha on being attentive to someone when they're speaking to you

Tags: halacha, parshanut-torah-comment, talmud-gemara, contemporary-halacha, conversation

BH

Does Halacha or any teaching in the Torah address the following scenarios:

A) When someone is talking to you, must you be attentive to show them respect that you're listening to what they're saying?

B) What to do if someone comes to talk to you and try to get your attention while you're already talking to another person (i.e. what to do to show respect to both)?

Comment: This seems to be a question of *derech eretz*. In the second case, typically the person you are talking to first should have priority, though there are ways to ensure the second person doesn't feel ignored. There are other factors to keep in mind, however. For instance, I have seen cases where the first person is monopolizing the time with languid and lackadaisical chit-chat, while the second person seems to be waiting to ask an important/urgent question. At the same time, there are people (lonely people, orphans, etc.) for whom there is an important emotional need to indulge their chit-chat.

Comment: What is the source that there is an emotional need to indulge in their conversation? How come it's like that and whats the source of that?